# Writing å, ä, ö in mathmode

Tags: math-mode, accents

I use a Swedish usepackage and when I write, for instance, `å` in formulas I get an error message `please use \mathaccent …`.

Here's what I try to write:

```
\begin{align} 
    \begin{split}
    {R} = \{alla\:tal\:på\:tallinjen\}
        \end{split}                 
\end{align}
```

At `\end{align}` I get the error message:

```
Please use \mathaccents for accents in math mode. \add@accent … spacefactor \spacefactor}\accent #1 #2\egroup \spacefactor …
1.54 \end{align}
I'm changing \accent to \mathaccent here: wish me luck.
(Accents are not the same in formulas as in text.)
```

I have tried with `\aa` but that doesn't work. Where is my failure?

Comment: You should use `\{\text{alla tal på tallinjen}\}`

Comment: Welcome to TeX.sx! Feel free to visit the [TeX.SX starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) that provides useful tips for new users to get the most out of the site. Oh, and välkommen!

Answer (score 14):

"Accents" in math mode can have a precise mathematical meaning. For instance `$\dot{a}$` isn't related to the use of the letter `ȧ` in words, but usually means a derivative with respect to time. Similarly, `$\ddot{a}$` is the second derivative and has nothing to do with `ä`.

Thus TeX disallows text accent commands in math mode: one should know what he/she is writing.

Your case is different: you want *text* inside a math formula; then use `\text`, which is provided by `amsmath` (you already load it).

```
\begin{align} 
    \begin{split}
    R = \{ \text{alla tal på tallinjen} \}
        \end{split}                 
\end{align}
```

By the way, *that* formula is unnecessarily complicated:

```
\begin{equation}
R = \{ \text{alla tal på tallinjen} \}
\end{equation}
```

not only is simpler, but provides for better vertical spacing.